# How to solve $e^{x-2} = x$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, exponential-function

A friend asked me what are the solutions to this equation.
I know for sure it has 2 solutions (thanks to Desmos) - `(0.159, 0.159)` and `(3.146, 3.146)`.

I have no idea even where to start solving this problem.

My knowledge in mathematics is sadly high school tier so please keep it as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is an analytical solution, you probably have to go with these numerical solutions.

Comment: do you know the ProdutLogarithen?

Comment: we get two real solutions

Comment: This is an [analitically unsolvable transcendental equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation)

Comment: If you want a little more precision you could look at [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5E(x-2)%3Dx) clicking more digits.

Comment: Well, considering that your knowledge is high school tier, what you can do is just simply graph the functions $f(x)=e^{x-2}$ and $g(x)=x$ on a graphics display calculator and find their points of intersection. Later, you may learn about the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), which allows you to solve this type of equation analytically. You may later learn about the [Newton-Raphson method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve it numerically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to use the function $W(x)$ which is defined to be the inverse of $xe^x$ on $(-1/e, \infty)$. This is to say, if $xe^x = y$ where $x>-1$, then  $W(y)=x$. Note that for $-e^{-1}<x<0$ we have two choices for what $W(x)$ can be. So, if $x < -1$ and $xe^x=y$, we define $W_{-1}$ such that $W_{-1}(y)=x$. We have
$$e^{x-2}=x$$
$$\frac 1 x e^x = e^2$$
Letting $u = -x$ gives us
$$-e^2=\frac{1}{u}e^{-u} = \frac{1}{ue^u}$$
$$ue^u = -e^{-2}$$
$$\implies u = W(-e^{-2}), W_{-1}(-e^{-2})$$
$$\implies x = -W(-e^{-2}), -W_{-1}(-e^{-2})$$

Comment: I understood everything except what is W(x). Is there a Wikipedia article you can refer me to about it? I couldn't find one...

Comment: Yeah, look up the Lambert W function.